# Facing large data spills for small datasets on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run some spark sql on NOA datasets available here:

[`https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/2021/`](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/2021/)

I am trying to run some query which involves grouping and sorting.

```
df
      .groupBy("COUNTRY_FULL")
      .agg(max("rank"), last("consecutive").as("consecutive"))
      .withColumn("maxDays", maxDaysTornodoUdf(col("consecutive")))
      .sort(col("maxDays").desc)
      .limit(1)
      .show()
```

The input size is just 50 MB zipped csvs and I am running this locally (4 cores).
These are the settings I use.

- spark.driver.memory: 14g
- spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.in.memory.threshold: 20000
- spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.spill.threshold : 20000
- spark.sql.shuffle.partitions : 400

I see too many disk spills for such a small data

```
21/08/16 10:23:13 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 54 spilling sort data of 416.0 MB to disk (371  times so far)
21/08/16 10:23:14 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 79 spilling sort data of 416.0 MB to disk (130  times so far)
21/08/16 10:23:14 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 53 spilling sort data of 400.0 MB to disk (240  times so far)
21/08/16 10:23:14 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 69 spilling sort data of 400.0 MB to disk (24  times so far)
21/08/16 10:23:16 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 54 spilling sort data of 416.0 MB to disk (372  times so far)
21/08/16 10:23:16 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 79 spilling sort data of 416.0 MB to disk (131  times so far)
```

However, when I check the Spark UI, the spillage doesnt seem to be much

[image]

Eventually the spark job terminates with error `Not Enough memory`
I do not understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 400 as `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, which is too much for the data size which you are dealing with.

Having more shuffle partitions for lesser amount of data causes more partitions/tasks and it will reduce the performance. Read best practices to configure shuffle partition [here](https://nealanalytics.com/blog/databricks-spark-jobs-optimization-techniques-shuffle-partition-technique-part-1/).

Try reducing shuffle partitions. You may try setting it to `spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I tried with lower value of 4, but it was the same story

Comment: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism )

Comment: still seeing the same logs. partitions is reduced to 4, but spillage still remains same